# SQL Randomization on Daily Basis

Tags: mysql, select, random

I have an SQL listing shops, but i would like to random the results on a daily basis.

For example today I list bat 2, 6, 9 etc
and tomorrow, 6,1,7,9 etc

Is there a way to implement this?

Comment: Are you trying to select random records or are you trying to randomize the resulting display?

Comment: i would like to random the results, but on a dialy basis. Thus if i today i run the query 10 times, the results for today will remain the same order, but if run tomorrow results should change

Answer (score 1):

With mysql you can write a query like this

select * from table order by rand(curdate()) limit 3

You can adapt it to other rdbms if you need.

Answer (score 0):

Is this for a website or...?

You could set up a cron job to run a script on a daily basis and change something to make different shops show up.

For example, you could create a table that contains the ID numbers of shops you want to show, and when your cron job runs it would delete all records from that table and insert new ones, determined randomly or however you want.

Comment: yes this is about a website ..... i will think about this, maybe by creating a coloumn with holding a random number that will change daily.